# Cannot access manager gui

Tags: java, tomcat8

I know this has been asked a few times (even if not for tomcat8) but I'm stumped having tried all those solutions.

I'm simply trying to access `http://localhost:8080/manager/html`.

The Tomcat service is definitely running, as I can access `http://localhost:8080/` fine. I've used the windows installer for Tomcat, so it's just configured everything through the install wizard.

`tomcat-users.xml`:

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
          version="1.0">
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-script"/>
<user username="myusername" password="password" roles="manager,manager-gui"/>
```

(I've tried the last line without `manager` and with `admin-gui` too.)

`conf/server.xml`:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />
```

I think that covers all the relevant bits for this to work. I assumed you don't need to move around any wars into webapps or anything. The log file seems to say it's loaded:

```
12-Feb-2015 22:47:02.038 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\manager
12-Feb-2015 22:47:02.089 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\manager has finished in 51 ms
```

And the access log says 404:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Feb/2015:22:54:26 +0000] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 404 1018
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I do notice that the `webapps/manager/WEB-INF` folder doesn't contain a `web.xml`. I definitely didn't delete it, it was just like this post-install. Should there be one?

Comment: Isn't the url just `http://localhost:8080/manager/` without the added "html" part?

Comment: I just clicked on the "Manager" link in the Tomcat home page, so I assume that's correct... `/manager/` 404's too though

Comment: Did you delete folders before starting it? I mean, you might have deleted the manager conetxt...

Comment: @user2393012 have you checked inside your webapps folder to see if it's even there?

Comment: @RobinJonsson it is indeed in the webapps folder

Comment: BTW host-manager works fine... I don't see a difference between the two. Should there be an xml file in `webapps/manager/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I couldn't work out why it wasn't working. So I just re-installed. This time I installed the Windows Service binary, checked "Manager" and "Host Manager" in the wizard - and it worked first time.

I do not notice anything different this time round. In fact, I'm more confused because now `tomcat-users.xml` contains this line but no `admin-gui` or `manager-gui` role is defined elsewhere in the file.

```
<user username="user" password="password" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui" />
```